# query selecting the correct element

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a calculator and I'm having trouble with using `querySelector` to select the correct operation. Right now, it's selecting "`divider`" since that is the first element in the html. This happens even if I click on the other operation keys.

I also tried using `querySelector` on the parent container `operationKeyContainer` but it gives me undefined. My reasoning would be that it would capture the children but I guess not.

Here is my code. I know I have a lot of work to refactor it but I just want to get it working now.

```html
<body>
  <main>
    <section class="equationDisplay display">test</section>
    <section class="answerDisplay display answerFont">0</section>
    <div class="divider"></div>
    <section class="calculatorButton">
      <section class="keyContainer operationKeyContainer">
        <button class="operationKey lightRed" data-key="divide">÷</button>
        <button class="operationKey lightRed" data-key="multiply">
          &times;
        </button>
        <button class="operationKey lightRed" data-key="add">+</button>
        <button class="operationKey lightRed" data-key="subtract">–</button>
      </section>
      <section class="keyContainer numberKeyContainer">
        <button class="numberKey" data-key="7">7</button>
        <button class="numberKey" data-key="8">8</button>
        <button class="numberKey" data-key="9">9</button>
        <button class="numberKey" data-key="4">4</button>
        <button class="numberKey" data-key="5">5</button>
        <button class="numberKey" data-key="6">6</button>
        <button class="numberKey" data-key="1">1</button>
        <button class="numberKey" data-key="2">2</button>
        <button class="numberKey" data-key="3">3</button>
        <button class="numberKey" data-key="0">0</button>
        <button class="numberKey" data-key=".">.</button>
        <button class="cancelKey" data-key="C">C</button>
      </section>
      <section class="keyContainer calculateKeyContainer">
        <button class="calculateKey teal" data-key="calculate">=</button>
      </section>
    </section>
  </main>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</body>
```

```js
document
  .querySelector(".calculatorButton")
  .addEventListener("click", clickButton);

const answerDisplay = document.querySelector(".answerDisplay");
const calculatorButton = document.querySelector(".calculatorButton");
const operationKey = document.querySelector(".operationKey"); // <------ I select the html element here

function clickButton(e) {
  if ("key" in e.target.dataset) {
    let button = e.target;
    let keyContent = button.dataset.key;
    let displayedNum = answerDisplay.textContent;
    let numberKey = button.classList.contains("numberKey");
    let operationKeyBool = button.classList.contains("operationKey");
    let previousKeyType = calculatorButton.dataset.previousKeyType;
    let calculateKey = button.classList.contains("calculateKey");

    if (numberKey == true) {
      if (displayedNum === "0" || previousKeyType == "operator") {
        displayedNum = answerDisplay.textContent;
        calculatorButton.dataset.previousKeyType = "number";
        document.querySelector(".answerDisplay").innerHTML = keyContent;
      } else {
        document.querySelector(".answerDisplay").innerHTML =
          displayedNum + keyContent;
      }
    }

    if (operationKeyBool == true) {
      calculatorButton.dataset.previousKeyType = "operator";
      const operator = operationKey.dataset.key; // <---------- Here is the problem
      let firstValue = displayedNum;
      console.log(operator);
    }

    if (calculateKey == true) {
      const secondValue = displayedNum;
      calculateKey();
    }
  }
}

function calculate(firstValue, secondValue, operator) {
  if (operator == "add") {
    return firstValue + secondValue;
  } else if (operator == "subtract") {
    return firstValue - secondValue;
  } else if (operator == "multiply") {
    return firstValue * secondValue;
  } else if (operator == "divide") {
    return firstValue / secondValue;
  }
}
```

Comment: `querySelector()` only returns the first element that matches the query, so in this case the first element with class `operationKey` which is divide. To return a NodeList of all the elements with the class you can use `querySelectorAll()`

Comment: Actually, you're getting the button from the target, which is good, just change `const operator = operationKey.dataset.key;` to `const operator = button.dataset.key;`

Answer (score 3):

Change this

```
const operationKey = document.querySelector(".operationKey");
```

To this

```
const operationKey = document.querySelectorAll(".operationKey");

document.querySelectorAll will return an array of all matching element which you can then loop through.

operationKey.forEach(currKey => {
    var keyValue = currKey.value;
});
```